# Updating parent component only after multiple child components have completed running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent react component with multiple child components that are created through a `.map()` function. I am passing in a function `addCallback()` as child props so I have a reference and can trigger all child's `handleRun()` function via the Parent.

I'm trying to update state of my Parent component to `running = true` when all children are running and to `running = false` and render said status on the parent when all children have completed running. However the state doesn't seem to update in the particular sequence I specify.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
let promise1 = this.setState({isRunning:  true},
            () => {
                this.state.childRef.map(x => x())
            });

Promise.all([promise1])
    .then(() => this.setState({isRunning: false}))
```

Here's the entire code in codesandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sunset-qzij1)

Would appreciate your help as I'm still pretty new to React (and Javascript in general). Thanks!

Comment: Is the expectation that the child apps would stay "running" after clicking the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause `runSomething` is not a `Promise`. You must change.

```
runSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.setState({ status: "running" });
     // simulate running something that takes 8s
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({ status: "idle" });
       resolve(true);
     }, 3000);
  });
}
```

A working sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-cloud-5o2um

Answer (score 2):

Using async in a function declaration automatically returns a Promise wrapped around whatever you are returning from your function. In your case, it's `undefined`. This is why your current code is not throwing any errors at the moment.

You will need a mechanism to wait for the `setTimeout`. Changing the `runSomething` function like this will work

```
  async runSomething() {
    this.setState({ status: "running" });

    // simulate running something that takes 8s
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ status: "idle" }, resolve);
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

Do notice the line `this.setState({ status: "idle" }, resolve);`. It makes sure that your promise resolves not only after the `setTimeout` but also after the child's state is changed to "idle". Which is the correct indication that your child component has moved to "idle" state.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-boyd-12hkj

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sandbox implementation of what you are trying to achieve. [Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-morse-m658e?fontsize=14)

Here i have created a state in parent component that will be updated when child is running.

```
this.state = {
  callbacks: [],
  components: [
    {
      index: 0, // we don't need this field its just for your info you can just create [true,false] array and index will represent component index.
      status: false
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      status: false
    }
  ]
};
```

When all the status in component array is true we update the idle status of parent to running.

```
  getAllRunningStatus() {
    let { components } = this.state;
    let checkAllRunning = components.map(element => element.status);
    if (checkAllRunning.indexOf(false) === -1) { // you can also use !includes(false) 
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

inside your render function

```
<h1>Parent {this.getAllRunningStatus() ? "running" : "idle"}</h1>
```

Note:- I have just written a rough code. You can optimise it as per your requirements. Thanks